# R: create new data.frame with time series from another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, time, time-series

I've a data.frame with structure:

```
        > str(prv) 
'data.frame':   13184 obs. of  7 variables:  
    $ date                   : Factor w/ 103 levels "2020-01-01",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...  
    $ code                   : int  13 13 13 13 13 17 17 17 21 21 ... 
    $ region                 : Factor w/ 21 levels "loc1","loc2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 12 12 ...  
    $ codprv                 : int  69 66 68 67 979 77 76 980 21 981 ...  
    $ denprv                 : Factor w/ 108 levels "city1","city2",..: 25 44 70 93 42 55 75 42 16 42 ...  
    $ shortprv               : Factor w/ 107 levels "","C1","C2","C3",..: 24 7 65 92 1 58 74 1 20 1 ...  
    $ sum                    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

and the data.frame is something like:

```
date       code region codprv denprv shortprv sum
2020-01-01 13   loc1   69     city1  C1       0
2020-01-01 13   loc1   66     city2  C2       0
2020-01-01 14   loc2   70     city3  C3       0
...
2020-01-02 13   loc1   68     city1  C3       0
2020-01-02 13   loc1   66     city2  C2       5
2020-01-02 14   loc2   70     city3  C3       1
...
2020-01-03 13   loc1   68     city1  C3       15
2020-01-03 13   loc1   66     city2  C2       7
2020-01-03 14   loc2   70     city3  C3       5
...
```

and so on...

I need to get:

```
date       city1 city2 city3 ... cityN
2020-01-01 0     0     0     ... n1
2020-01-02 0     5     1     ... n2
2020-01-03 15    7     5     ... n3
```

I recently learned using R and I used it only to perform statistical analysis and not time series analysis.

It's not so hard to do it manually, but i want to know a right way to convert (and to learn how to (re)use it independently).

Sorry for my language.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a reproducible example, you've nearly gotten it, next time please use `dput(head(your_data))` to provide your data in a readable format.

Answer (score 1):

You need the function `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`:

```
df <- data.frame(date = rep(seq(as.Date("2020/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 4), each = 3),
                 denprv = rep(c("city1", "city2", "city3"), 4),
                 sum = 1:12)
library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(df, names_from = denprv, values_from = sum)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  date       city1 city2 city3
  <date>     <int> <int> <int>
1 2020-01-01     1     2     3
2 2020-01-02     4     5     6
3 2020-01-03     7     8     9
4 2020-01-04    10    11    12
```

Your data is in the long format and you want a wide format. Check out information about [tidy data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).